# getting the path to an app by app id in an OS X shell

Tags: macos, terminal, bundle

Given an application identifier is it possible to get the current path to the app bundle from the OS X terminal?

For example given the id `com.apple.terminal` it would return `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> osascript -e "POSIX path of (path to application id \"com.apple.terminal\")"